# Record Clicks on Modal Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I have a page that catalogues media (think similar to an instagram page). The media is viewable on modals, and I'd like to record a "view count" for each piece of media. So whenever the modal containing that media is toggled open, it records a view.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="media-number-999">Click to view Media 999!</button>
<div class="modal" id="media-number-999">Media #999 viewable here!</div>
```

I also have a page set up where visiting that page automatically increases the viewcount by 1, and then redirects elsewhere (using django)

```
urls.py:
path('views/<id>/', views.media_views, name="mediaviews"),

views.py:
def media_views(request,id):
    Media.objects.filter(id=id).update(views=F('views') + 1)
    return redirect('media_detail', id=id)
```

The reason I'm doing this is so that I can then reference the viewcount in the database to use for sorting/filtering/etc.

How can I make a button that both opens the modal, and also records a visit to /views/999/ ? Also open to alternative approaches if there are better ways! I've tried to figure out how to use Ajax to do this but haven't had any luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add an onclick function to

   </button data-toggle="modal" data-target="media-number-999" onclick="recordview(999)">Click to view Media 999!<//button>
2. Create a new endpoint on your app that has the following format: /record/{id}
3. Make a function recordview() that makes a simple HTTP request (No need for AJAX) to your new endpoint
4. Remove the `Media.objects.filter(id=id).update(views=F('views') + 1)`in media_views to avoid double recording (From when they clicked vs when they opened) or change the model in media_views

(There is no / at the start of  but i had to add it otherwise StackOverflow wouldn't format it properly. Make sure to remove it (And let me know if you know how to format it without the damn slash!)

Comment: This worked! Thanks! As far as making the code show up, if you type the code, highlight it, and click ctrl + k, it should work!